# Use resource file.resx for WPF Controls content attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, controls, resx

I'm trying to make a 'dictionary' for my WPF application. So I created a strings.resx file inside properties. In there I create names like 'isoffline' with a value: 'Is off-line'. So in code i can use Properties.strings.isoffline to get the right value, but how do I get the right value in XAML?

For instance I have a checkbox, and I want the content to display 'Is off-line'. On a different site I found something like:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="isoffline" Content="{x:Static properties:strings.isoffline}"
```

Yet this does not work. How can I reach properties.strings.isoffline within XAML?

Comment: Just set the Access Modifier to `public`.

Comment: I tried but it did not work...